# Dismiss mat-sidenav on click outside

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material2, angular-components, angular-material-6

I'm trying to close my sidebar whenever user clicks somewhere not in it. I've tried two-way data-binding and now I'm trying with [rxjs' `Subject`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#subject)

### AppTemplate

```
<app-sidenav [openedSubject]="openedSubject"></app-sidenav>
```

### AppComponent

```
openedSubject = new Subject<boolean>();

@HostListener('click', ['$event']) clickedInside($event) {
    this.openedSubject.next(false);
}
```

### SidenavComponent

```
@Input() openedSubject: Subject<boolean>;
@ViewChild('sidenav') sidenav: MatSidenav;

ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.openedSubject.subscribe(opened => {
        if(this.sidenav.opened) opened || this.sidenav.toggle();
    });
}

toggle() {
  this.openedSubject.next(!this.sidenav.opened);
}
```

### SidenavTemplate

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav><mat-toolbar color="primary">Menu</mat-toolbar>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content>
        <mat-toolbar color="primary">
            <button (click)="toggle()">toggle</button>
        </mat-toolbar>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-sidenav-experiments

---

But there seems to be a logic error. The [`click` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click) covers the whole document, whereas it should exclude the sidenav and toolbar.

Comment: Your stackblitz doesn't have any of the code in your question. It also never shows the hello component. Please ask **one** question, with the relevant code.

Comment: I thought it was better to show a small bit of code, rather than a huge version with lots of dependencies, like this [WiP]: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-sidenav-experiments

Comment: This doesn't work with AsyncSubject. Why don't you use a regular Subject?

Comment: @JBNizet Okay I've updated the text and added a new stackblitz. It should be sufficiently representative now.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. The issue was my use of `HostListener`, whereas I really just wanted to `(click)` like so:

```
<sidenav [openedSubject]="openedSubject"></sidenav>

<fake-route-view (click)="dismissSidebar()"></fake-route-view>
```

Full working version: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-sidenav-experiments